# Laravel: Login and Password in different tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-authentication, laravel-models

I'am a new in Laravel, but not in php and sql.

So I have Users and Users_password tables.

The User table looks like:

```
  user_rec_id |  FirstName    | sName  | created_at   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
       1      |      Smith    |  Ala   |     date     |
       2      |      Smith    |  Doe   |     date     |
       3      |      Marks    |  Ill   |     date     |
```

- user_rec_id - is a record id in TABLE

The Users_password table looks like:

```
  pwd_rec_id | pwd_user_rec_id   | pwd_sHash   | created_at   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1        |      1            |     #112    |     date     |
    2        |      2            |     $559    |     date     |
    3        |      1            |     !555    |     date     |
```

- pwd_rec_id - is a record id in TABLE
- pwd_user_rec_id - is a primary key in User table.

Logging data must be newest. I mean sign in with Login 'Smith Ala' and password '#112' (user id: 1) will be failed.
Beacause actual Login and password for user_id 1 is  'Smith Doe' + '!555'

So, how I can make a currect model for User and UserPassword?

After slove my probem, I'd like that creating new user must be like User->create or something like that. And working Auth::attempt() by FirstName, sName [in User table] and pwd_sHash [in Users_password]

Comment: Have a **user_history** table, keep only  current data in the users table and forget all that rubbish.

Comment: It's too easy. I hear that Laravel is a POWERFULL and choice it as my first framework. In clear php I'll make it in 2-5 more minutes. But with Laravel I already spend 4 days before asking on stackoverflow. I believe that it can be maked on Laravel.

Comment: I can understand that you want to keep old names and passwords, but to keep this in the same table isn't wise. There are several reasons: 1. One column in your table contains two different sets of data: Current data and old data. That's bad practice. 2. It complicates the operations you need to perform on the table, increasing the likelihood of bugs and security problems. So, if you want to keep data, use another table, which you only access when you actually need the old data.

Comment: `I believe that it can be maked on Laravel`...it can, but first you need to redesign your database to a sensible structure, as both the commenters above have mentioned. It's unclear why half the history is in the users table (which is also mixed in with current data) and the other half is in a different table? It really does not make sense. Just have one "users" table with all current user data in it, and a "users_history" table with all historical user data in it. That will make all your implementation much simpler.

Comment: Okay. After reading it, I'll make an user_history and users_password_history tables. But anyway, the question is still on. How to do it in Laravel make model of user or user_passowrd when login (firstname and sName) and password in diffetent tables?

Comment: You don't. You redesign it properly, and then the problem goes away. There is never any need to have this data in different tables.

Comment: why do you need a separate users_password_history table? Why can't an old password go into the user_history table as well?

Comment: The user table have more then 3 fields. In furtune it will be like 35 or mode fields.

Comment: The user table have more then 3 fields. In furtune it will be like 35 or mode fields.
And if I'll megree a password table into user, that will result of: 1 when user (or admin) change just pwd, all of 35-50 colums that was NOT CHANGET will be saved in history. I dont need that. So I really need to have two tables users and users_passowrd. And I still need to slove that problem in Laravel

Comment: when a user changes their first name, all of 35-50 colums that was NOT CHANGET will be saved in history. WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE?

Comment: because that will be much rarely in my system

Comment: So??? It gives you a complete state of the dags at any given moment of change. That's a good thing, from an audit point of view. Are you concerned about usage of space? In any modern computer the difference will not be anything noticeable

Comment: Yes. A Space. Anyway I need a solution of my problem.

Comment: You've been given one. Space will not be an issue, unless your disk is unusually tiny

Comment: This solution makes other issue.

Comment: What other issue? It certainly solves the one you've got now. A better database design will always solve more problems than it can cause

Comment: In any better database design, will always spawn a problem like that one. I still need a solve

Comment: No, you don't. It's an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You're looking for the wrong solution to the wrong problem. You didn't answer what issue the redesign would cause.

Comment: @Danny Laravel is an opinionated framework that implements a lot of good practices into it's logic. While breaking out of them is possible, it's often not worth the work and effort as the main issue is the why not the how. For your case you would have to implement your own UserProvider that performs a join of your two tables, as none of the existing providers have a need to do that. However this may be a bit of an advanced topic and a beginner of the framework should have no need to do that. If you are porting the db from somewhere, better to modify the users table to fit the default migration

Comment: another quick fix type of option might be to create a view of these two tables, and have that new corresponding model be the model you authenticate against